# Creating dictionary from a sentence where first character is key and word is value

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x, dictionary

> I have a sentence called "myString" , What i am trying to do is that,
>   creating a dictionary from the sentence where first character of the
>   each word must be the key of the dictionary( white , w), and all words
>   starting with that character must be the values of that
>   keys.('w',['white','with']).
>
> I have already written some python code. I want to know which code
>   snippet is better or is there any better approach to this problem.
>   Like a Dictionary Comprehension.?

**Output i want to generate.**

> {'w': ['white', 'with', 'well'], 'h': ['hats', 'hackers', 'hackers',
>   'hackable', 'hacker', 'hired'] ...}

```
 myString = "White hats are hackers employed with the efforts of
 keeping data safe from other hackers by looking for loopholes and
 hackable areas This type of hacker typically gets paid quite well and
 receives no jail time due to the consent of the company that hired
 them"
```

counterDict = {}

```
    for word in myString.lower().split():
      fChar = word[0]
      if fChar not in counterDict:
        counterDict[fChar] = []
      counterDict[fChar].append(word)  
    print(counterDict)
```

## Using dictionary.get method

```
for word in myString.lower().split():
  fChar = word[0]
  counterDict.get(word,[]).append(word)
print(counterDict)
```

## collections.defaultdict()

```
import collections
counterDict = collections.defaultdict(list)
for word in myString.lower().split():
  fChar = word[0]
  counterDict[fChar].append(word)
print(counterDict)
```

## collections.defaultdict( ) + list comprehension.

```
import collections
counterDict = collections.defaultdict(list)
[ counterDict[word[0]].append(word) for word in myString.lower().split() ]
print(counterDict)
```

Comment: Improvement of working code belongs in CodeReview.StackExchange.com

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any way to achieve result using dictionary comprehension.?

Comment: Your solutions labeled `collections.Counter` aren't using collections.Counter, they're using collections.defaultdict. Semantics aside, my opinion is that defaultdict (without list comp) is the best approach.

Comment: It was a typo, I have edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dict comprehension for assigning default values to the counterDict, and then append:

```
myString = "White hats are hackers employed with the efforts of
keeping data safe from other hackers by looking for loopholes and
hackable areas This type of hacker typically gets paid quite well and
receives no jail time due to the consent of the company that hired
them"

new_string = myString.split()

counterDict = {i[0].lower():[] for i in new_string}

for i in new_string:
    counterDict[i[0].lower()].append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your purpose:

```
from collections import defaultdict

counter_dict = defaultdict(list)
word_list = [(word[0], word) for word in my_string.lower().split()] #index 0 and the word is taken

for letter, word in word_list:
    counter_dict[letter].append(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you like one-liners and obsessed with *`comprehensions`(like me), you can combine dictionary comprehension with
list comprehension:

```
new_string = myString.lower().split() #helps readability


counterDict = {i[0]:[z for z in new_string if z[0] == i[0]] for i in new_string}
```